# How do Windows domain clients behave if the on site domain controller is/goes offline?

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller

If I have Windows PCs that are joined to a domain and the DC on the **same site** goes offline, what kind of behavior can I expect on the clients

a) when local DC is already offline when Windows boots? Will it just take another DC or does it fail because the local DC still has a DNS record and Windows does normaly uses the DC in the same subnet?

b) when a user is already  logged on, when DC goes offline?
How long does it take until Windows querys other DCs for new tickets and uses the secondary DNS?

Given the following conditions:

- there are other DCs in our datacenter and on other sites and these are reachable by the clients on this site
- All clients have the datacenter DC as secondary DNS
- DHCP is done by another local server

Answer (score 2):

a) Windows will startup connecting to the DC in the data center b) within a few seconds of attempting to access a resource that results in an authentication challenge. (Or DNS request for a name lookup that is not cached).

It's fairly quick and easy to test this yourself by sinkholing the local DC in the hosts file on a client on a test system/environment. This is a very common configuration and works well.

Domain Controllers are also "cached", so that the client doesn't have to perform the rather complex DC Locator lookup every time. These entries expire after a few hours, and the process is mostly transparent and does not affect this scenario.

Modern clients (Windows 10) by default perform DNS lookups in parallel,  so the DNS part may be less impacted, assuming that parallel lookups haven't been disabled.

---

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/how-domain-controllers-are-located

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/enabling-clients-to-locate-the-next-closest-domain-controller

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/manage/dc-locator-changes

https://superuser.com/questions/969171/multihomed-windows-10-dns-resolution-timeouts

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly depending on if you have a properly configured DNS, both on DCs and on clients, and what FSMO role the local DC holds. If everything is configured properly, and the DC is offline only for a short time, you shouldn't see much impact, if at all, regardless if a user has logged in, or whether a client is already up.